# Android Database: Multiple Instances of one Database Table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design, multiple-instances

Let's say I am planning on creating an app that tracks locations for various indicated periods of time, and stores them in a database.

I'd only need one table version with schema consisting of an **_id, longitude, latitude,** and **time**. I do not want to store each instance in the same table.

Considering I will be logging many (an unknown number) different instances of this one table, how do I go about creating my database class?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why would you want to have multiple tables of same kind inside your database but the solution will be to create a new table each instance or some predetermined number of instances. Each table name will be different as you cannot have duplicate tables in your database. You can also have another table in your database which keeps the track of table names you create. so for example lets start with table1.

you have an SQL statement

```
Create Table Table1 (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    Long real not null,
    Lat real not null,
      Time real not null
);
```

Use this SQL as template and just change the Table name from Table1 to Table2, Table3, Table#

and also insert into another table some info about the table you create.

This is one way to do it.

Hope you got some idea's.

Comment: is it possible to pass a unique table name when creating a new table? for example, when I create a new instance of the DB in my activity, can i pass the table name instance from my activity to my DB class, and have the DB class create the table instance from the passed String?

Comment: well all you are doing is running an SQL statement on Database doesn't matter if that statement creates Tables, Inserts data into existing tables. Just Treat it as another database operation, nothing too fancy